# How do I transfer only single vertex groups between objects?

Tags: vertex-groups

I have two identical models and want to transfer a single vertex group from one of them to the other. I do NOT want to transfer all of the vertex groups, just a single one out of the list.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 12):

1. Select object where you'd like the vertex group to copy to. You don't need to create empty vertex group there as it will be added automatically, still it's possible to do for testing purposes.
2. With this object still selected,  <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>RMB</kbd> to select object which has original vertex group.
3. Choose *Copy Vertex Group* entry from drop-down menu. The thing is that you should select mesh with vertex group to be copied *last*.

   [image: GIF with copying vertex groups]

Comment: This way transfers all the groups from original object (selected last) to the desired one (selected first). So it's handy but won't work as expected if more than one group is being copied.

Comment: I tried this to copy a single group as in the question title, but it replaces all groups. If you hover mouse over "Copy vertex group to selected" the tooltip says "Replace vertex groups of select" which is hardly a "Copy Single" and more of a "Replace All".

Answer (score 6):

There are several ways to do so. The recommended one is by using **Transfer Weights** operator:

1. First select the source object, then select target object by holding <kbd>Shift</kbd>.
2. Switch to **Weight Paint** mode, find **Transfer Weights** button from *Weight Tools* panel in the tool tab.
3. In <kbd>F6</kbd> panel, set Vertex Mapping method to Topology. Then set the source/target layer as expected, and Mix Mode if needed.

P.S.:

1. The operator will automatically create a new vertex group for you if there is no vertex groups on target object.
2. The operation will transfer all vertex weights, including zero-weight data. To fix it, press **Clean** button in *Weight Tools* panel, keep the *Limit* value as default 0.000.

Comment: I see. Then see my updated answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Duplicate the model with many vertex groups. Keystroke Shift-D. Let us name the new object Mesh02.

Delete the undesired vertex groups from Mesh02.  Vertex Groups can be deleted or added freely.  Mesh02 now has the desired vertex group of your choice.

You have stated your models are identical.