# All my characters have lost their bone vertex groups. Is there a way to bring them back?

Tags: animation, armature, parent, blend-files, vertex-groups

I worked on my project on a different laptop yesterday, then took the new file back to my own computer today. While working on the other laptop i didnt do any character animation, only camera animation, materials and lights.

Now that i opened the file on my own laptop again the armatures are moving as they should but all the meshes are in restmode, being dragged along by their armatures. Their bone vertex groups have dissappeared. Does anyone know if there's a way to bring them back easily or do i have to do everything i did yesterday all over again.. ? Any help very much appreaciated <3

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share one object of your original file so that we see if it also loose its vertex groups? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: @moonboots https://pasteall.org/blend/8d5525d03f834706bf372a31c90840dc here i added one character from the original file where the vertex groups are fine and the same character with the missing vertex groups. is that what you meant?

Comment: I don't know why you have lost the vertex groups, this is weird, also if you are able to append the good object with its vertex groups why don't you do it for all of them on your own computer? Edit: If you want to copy the vertex groups from an object to another you can use Copy Vertex Groups to Selected: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/45898/how-do-i-transfer-only-single-vertex-groups-between-objects